# Converting datetime to varchar with just the date portion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If `SELECT GETDATE()` produces `2014-09-05 11:06:38.927` and `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 101)` produces `09/05/2014`, why, then, does `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '2014-09-05 11:06:38.927', 101)` produce `2014-09-05 11:06:38.927` instead of `09/05/2014`?

Comment: Why don't you just let the application do the formatting? Also why do you want to present the date in an ambiguous format? Do you think nobody will ever come to your page from the UK or Canada or just about anywhere outside of the US and assume that that is May 9th instead of September 5th?

Comment: Thanks smarty pants.  It's great that you assume this is a web application, but in reality, it's a non-client-facing desktop application running in a small firm located firmly within the U.S.A., so there's not risk of any UK or Canadian citizens using it.  Regardless, it was more of a hypothetical question anyway.  Your point has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value in the third statement that you are converting is already a string.  Convert will convert the value and drop the time if you first convert the string to a date:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST('2014-09-05 11:06:38.927' as DATETIME), 101)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 101)
```

is converting a datetime to varchar

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '2014-09-05 11:06:38.927', 101)
```

is converting a varchar to a varchar

try:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), convert(datetime, '2014-09-05 11:06:38.927'), 101)
```

and you should see similar results as your first query.